# Why is the static modifier necessary in this code?

Tags: c#, object, static

I've read about `static`. I know that it's a prefix that is accessible only by non-objects. But I can't understand why `Easter` has to be `static`?

```
class JsonFile
{
    public List<Holiday> StandardHolidays = new List<Holiday>();
    public List<ChangingHoliday> ChangingHoliday = new List<ChangingHoliday>();

    public static Easter Easter = new Easter();
    public static DaysToOffset GoodFriday = new DaysToOffset("Good Friday", Easter, -2);
}
```

I don't get the concept of `static` yet. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Where is `static`?

Comment: To achieve this, move initialization into an explicit non-static constructor, like this: `class JsonFile
{
    public List<Holiday> StandardHolidays;
    public List<ChangingHoliday> ChangingHolidays;

    public Easter Easter;
    public DaysToOffset GoodFriday;

    public JsonFile() { StandardHolidays = new List<Holiday>();
    ChangingHolidays = new List<ChangingHoliday>();

    Easter = new Easter();
    GoodFriday = new DaysToOffset("Good Friday", Easter, -2);

}` If you have several constructor overloads defined, do not forget to "chain" the `: this()` constructor from everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

During initialization you cannot have an instance of `Easter` but you require one when you use

```
public DaysToOffset GoodFriday = new DaysToOffset("Good Friday", Easter, -2);
```

so `Easter` has to be `static` in order that its existence in `GoodFriday` would be valid.

Comment: Can you explain why I cannot have an instance of Easter?

Comment: He can work around that by moving the initialization of the fields (or even just the fourth of them) into a non-static constructor.

Comment: @Code_Steel  Because the compiler can rearrange these - there is no guarantee that `Easter` will be initialized before `GoodFriday`, so without using `static` you might have gotten a `NullReferenceException`. Read the duplicate question it has a great explanation by Oded.

Comment: @Idos OP explains why in the answer.

Comment: The explanation mentioned (in your comment) is incorrect. I added a comment in the linked thread, under Oded's answer there.